# How do I get a value from a json array using a key

Tags: python, arrays, json

I'm reading a json and want to get the label field with a specific id. What I currently have is:

```
with open("local_en.json") as json_file:
    parsed_dict = json.load(json_file)
    print(parsed_dict)                         # works
    print(parsed_dict["interface"])            # works
    print(parsed_dict["interface"]["testkey"])
```

My json has data blocks (being "interface" or "settings") and those data blocks contain arrays.

```
{
    "interface":[
    {"id": "testkey", "label": "The interface block local worked!"}
    {"id": "testkey2", "label": "The interface block local worked, AGAIN!"}
    ],
    "settings":[
    
    ],
    "popup_success":[
        
    ],
    "popup_error":[
    
    ],
    "popup_warning":[
    
    ],
    "other_strings":[
    
    ]
}
```

Comment: Value for `"interface"` key contain a list, so you need to pick an index from this list in order to get into one of the dictionaries with `"id"` keys. And by the way, `"testkey"` is a value, not a key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can "find" the element in the `interface` list via a list-comprehension, and fetch the label from that element. For instance:

```
label = [x['label'] for x in parsed_dict['interface'] if x['id'] == 'testkey'][0]
```

If you cannot assume that the relevant id exists, then you can wrap this in a try-except, or you can get a list of the labels and validate that it isn't of length 0, or whatever you think would work best for you.

```
key = 'testkey'
labels = [x['label'] for x in parsed_dict['interface'] if x['id'] == key]
assert len(labels) > 0, f"There's no matching element for key {key}"
label = labels[0]  # Takes the first if there are multiple such elements in the interface array
```

And while you're at it, you might want to explicitly deal with there being multiple elements with the same id, etc.

---

Clarification regarding your error(s):
`parsed_dict["interface"]` is a list, so you can index it with `int`s (and slices and stuff, but that's besides the point), and *not* with `str`ings.
Each of the list elements is a `dict`, with two `key`s: `id` and `label`, so even if you were to take a specific element, say -

```
el = parsed_dict["interface"][0]
```

you *still* couldn't do `el['testkey']`, because that's a `value` of the dict, not a `key`.

You *could* check if the `id` is the one you're looking for though, via -

```
if el['id'] == 'testkey':
    print('Yup, this is it')
    label = el['label']
```

In fact, the single line I gave above is really just shorthand for running over all the elements with a loop and doing just that...

Answer (score 1):

You need to browse through all the values and check if it matches expected value. Because values are not guaranteed to be unique in a dictionary, you can't simply refer to them directly like you do with keys.

```
print([el for el in d["interface"] if "testkey" in el.values()])
```

Comment: There must be another way to access that string inside the json without searching. Maybe one has to use something else than a dict